# Download a file with php and polymer

Tags: php, polymer-1.0, webclient

I'm having some trouble with this one. I have found some helpful scripts on the web and have been modifying them for my needs. However, I can't seem to download a file. It will respond back with the contents of the file but doesn't download it. I am using Polymer 1.0+ for my client side and PHP for my server side. The client side code to download a file is as follows:

```
   <!--THIS IS THE HTML SIDE-->
   <iron-ajax   
        id="ajaxDownloadItem"
        url="../../../dropFilesBackend/index.php/main/DownloadItem"
        method="GET"
        handle-as="document"
        last-response="{{downloadResponse}}"
        on-response="ajaxDownloadItemResponse">
    </iron-ajax>

//THIS IS THE JAVASCRIPT THAT WILL CALL THE "iron-ajax" ELEMENT
downloadItem:function(e){ 
    this.$.ajaxDownloadItem.params = {"FILENAME":this.selectedItem.FILENAME,
                                      "PATH":this.folder};
    this.$.ajaxDownloadItem.generateRequest();
},
```

The server side code is as follows (the url is different because I do some url modification to get to the correct script):

```
function actionDownloadItem(){
    valRequestMethodGet();
    $username = $_SESSION['USERNAME'];
    if(validateLoggedIn($username)){
        $itemName = arrayGet($_GET,"FILENAME");
        $path = arrayGet($_GET,"PATH");
        $username = $_SESSION['USERNAME'];

        $downloadItem = CoreFilePath();
        $downloadItem .= "/".$_SESSION['USERNAME']."".$path."".$itemName;

        DownloadFile($downloadItem);
    }
    else {
        echo "Not Logged In.";
    }
}

function DownloadFile($filePath) {
    //ignore_user_abort(true);
    set_time_limit(0); // disable the time limit for this script
    //touch($filePath);
    //chmod($filePath, 0775);

    if ($fd = fopen($filePath, "r")) {
        $fsize = filesize($filePath);//this returns 12
        $path_parts = pathinfo($filePath);//basename = textfile.txt
        $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);//this returns txt
        $header = headerMimeType($ext); //this returns text/plain
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$path_parts["basename"].'"'); // use 'attachment' to force a file download
        header("Content-type: $header");
        header("Content-length: $fsize");
        header("Cache-control: private"); //use this to open files directly
        while(!feof($fd)) {
            $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
            echo $buffer;
        }
    }
    fclose ($fd);
}
```

Any help on this one would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will need to write the read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will need the file handle

```
$pathToSave = '/home/something/something.txt';

$writeHandle = fopen($pathToSave, 'wb');
```

Then, while you are reading the download, write to the file instead of echoing

```
fwrite($writeHandle, fread($fd, 2048));
```

Finally, after writing to the file finished close the handle

```
fclose($writeHandle);
```

I neglect the error check, you should implement your own.

Comment: This works really well. I tested this will multiple types. However, I would like to have some sort of download happen in the browser so that I can see it is happening instead of behind the scenes with no visual update.

Comment: I was able to download it through the browser by opening the url to my php code without using iron-ajax. EX: window.location.href = "path/to/php/function";